# How to collapse status bar's dropdown menu on third party apps?

Tags: android, status

What I wish to do is what Surelock does, I can already stop the user from acessing the status bar's menu, my problem is I can only do that for my app.
I need help doing it the way surelock does it, for every app launched within my app I need to collapse the status bar menu.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WindowManager to draw a View over the touch area for the notification bar that consumes all the touch events.

Keep in mind that this breaks expected behaviour on Android, and is an anti practice. If the notification bar is visible, it should be expandable. I doubt too many users will appreciate you doing this.

Comment: I currently override the onWindowFocusChanged method, and collapse the statusbar, however it only works for my application.

Comment: Interesting idea - agreed its an anti-pattern, but always nice to know about such hacks.

Comment: Hi @Raghav Sood, could you perhaps share some code regarding how to make a View consume all touch events? I've managed to draw the View over the status bar, but the notification bar can still be touched and expandable as a result.